# Joomla Mega Menu without a dependent plugin/module

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla1.5, megamenu

I've been searching for a solution to this problem endlessly and thus far, haven't found one. The idea is that there are some templates that have a built in system but they require you to use their template in order to get it working.

I just want a menu (like the one here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/) to work in Joomla without any dependent plugin/module.

Did anyone manage to do this in Joomla at all? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want something as specific as that you need a existing module or you can create your own menu module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways for you do get this done:

1. Create the whole thing by yourself (if you can)
2. Create your template on the basis of a joomla template framework like T3, Gantry or Warp
3. Extract the needed code for the mega menu from one of thoose template frameworks i mentioned (i would take gantry here)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved it using this module: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/drop-a-tab-menus/11578

Answer (score 0):

JUX [Joomla Mega Menu](http://www.joomlaux.com/extensions/mega-menu/jux-mega-menu.html) is the most completed and easy to use Joomla menu module which allows you to display a ton of content in menu item including text, images, module and articles. Works beautifully with Joomla 2.5 and Joomla 3.x. 
http://www.joomlaux.com/extensions/mega-menu/jux-mega-menu.html